# SELECT CASE Syntax Error

Tags: sql, t-sql, select-case

I have the following @temp table :

```
------------------------------------
|Condition_ID   Operator   Order    |
|     1            ==        1      |
|     2            <>        3      |
|     3            ==        2      |
------------------------------------
```

I want to implement a SELECT CASE that will output a certain message depending on the Operator

However this throws me an `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PRINT'.` error.

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN Operator LIKE '=='
        THEN PRINT 'EQUALS'
    WHEN Operator LIKE '<>'
        THEN PRINT 'NOT EQUALS'
END AS Operator
FROM @temp
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `PRINT`

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN Operator LIKE '=='
        THEN 'EQUALS'
    WHEN Operator LIKE '<>'
        THEN 'NOT EQUALS'
END AS Operator
FROM @temp
```

You can't use a `PRINT` inside a `SELECT`, and you don't need to - the `SELECT` will retrieve the appropriate value for you.

Comment: you need to add an 'END' before the 'AS'. good answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot mix `PRINT` and `SELECT`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Operator LIKE '=='
            THEN 'EQUALS'
            WHEN Operator LIKE '<>'
            THEN 'NOT EQUALS'
       END AS Operator
FROM @temp
```

Comment: Does that mean I cannot use `PRINT`?

Comment: Do you explicitly need PRINT?

Comment: No, but I would like to know if it possible to use it.

Comment: You can't use select and print at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

this works ::

```
   SELECT CASE
    WHEN opr LIKE '=='
        THEN 'EQUALS'
    WHEN opr LIKE '<>'
        then 'NOT EQUALS'
    else
        'wrong i/p'
    end
as operator
FROM tbl1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,there is no print option

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN Operator LIKE '=='
        THEN 'EQUALS'
        WHEN Operator LIKE '<>'
        THEN 'NOT EQUALS'
   END AS Operator
   FROM @temp
```